# How do i count the number of 'Excellent' results from a survey question and store it as an integer in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a survey with 16 questions, each question has the same answer set:

```
Excellent, Good, OK, Poor.
```

The answers are stored in a Mysql table called `answers` and is structured as below, where `q1, q2,q3..` are questions for each time the survey is completed.

```
Table: Answers

question_id    answer
```

How do i count the number of `Excellent` results from each question and store it as an integer in a different mysql table called answers structured q1,q2,q3,etc ?

Comment: You mean questions and stored are as a comma separated value in a single value ?

Comment: The answers for q1 are stored as varchar in a mysql table. The answers can be 1 of 4.
Excellent, Good, OK, Poor.
I need to count the number of times Excellent, Excellent, Good, OK, Poor.appears and store it as an integer in another table

Comment: Your question above and the comment below are two separate questions. I answered your question assuming you were only interested in count of  'Excellent'  for each question and wanted to store those values in a separate table under each question. I don't now why you would materialize the result into a separate table though. A simple query would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question

> *"How do i count the number of 'Excellent' results from each question and store it as an integer in a different mysql table called answers
>   structured q1,q2,q3,etc ?"*

You could do something like this

```
create table if not exists answers_structured as

select
sum(q1='Excellent') as q1,
sum(q2='Excellent') as q2,
sum(q3='Excellent') as q3
from answers;
```